# Paypal Return Value to Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have created a Paypal  send payment button from Paypal developers account on my aspx page from which a user can send me payments but i wonder how  i can get a unique key, about which user had made me payment.
How can i recognize which person paid me through Paypal.
I can pass any value (his mail id, name, phone number or a unique key) but i don't know how Paypal will return values to me so i can maintain user payment history in DB 
is there any good forum on this ? 
Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CUSTOM parameter for that.  It will hold up to 256 characters, so if you need more than one value you can do something like value1|value2|etc and then split it back up on the other end.

When you include the CUSTOM parameter in API requests or standard buttons it will come back in IPN notifications so you can automate processing utilizing that data however you need to.

Comment: and what is about PDT ? i have heard about this term to get values from paypal account?

Comment: PDT is essentially the same thing as IPN except that it sends the data to your return URL instead of a silent POST to a script separate from the checkout flow.  It sends the same data, though, and you verify it in the same way.  The thing is, there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your site when using Payments Standard, even with Auto-Return enabled, so it's not wise to handle post-payment processing tasks on the return URL.

Comment: so it means if we use PDT and user close the page immediately after sending paypal payment then no data will be return ?and we can lose paypal user details ? but in case of IPN this won't happen and when user immediately close browser pager or not return to our website  we can get its data or information ?is that point you have behind IPN ?

Comment: That is correct.  IPN will always trigger regardless of the user's action (as long as the transaction was indeed completed).  It also allows you to handle lots of other things like refunds, disputes, pending payments (when they clear or fail), etc.

Comment: The [IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) is a great resource and includes a [list of parameters that IPN sends](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) for most transactions.  Here's an [article specific to C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84538/Setting-up-PayPal-Instant-Payment-Notification-IPN).